# Unable to load values of HashMap from Spring XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, hashmap

I have written a xml file for hashmap.
There are two issues, xml file shows a red-cross but neither error message appears when mouse pointer hovers over it nor in 'problem' section.
Second issue is, It compiles well, but values key-values are not transferred to the hashmap object. HashMap object in class remains 'null'

[image: Here you can see the red-cross]

XML for hash map is:

```
<bean id="GateKeeper" class="com.smarttrade.domain.GateKeeper"/>

<bean id="ClientToRateMap" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Integer">
            <entry key="A" value=1 />
            <entry key="B" value=2 />
            <entry key="C" value=3 />
            <entry key="D" value=4 />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and class is

```
public class GateKeeper {

    @Resource
    @Qualifier("ClientToRateMap")
    HashMap<String, Integer> ClientToRateMap;

    public void ApplyRateLimitPerClient(ClientRequestEntity client) {
        System.out.println(ClientToRateMap);     // Ouput is NULL
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the map is created, but not injected since you don't have `<annotation-config/>` in your xml.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your two issues with your code, follow the below steps:

(1) You need to define the spring namespaces in the xml as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<!-- add your beans here -->

</beans>
```

(2) In order to spring container to find your bean, you need to mark your `GateKeeper` class with `@Component`